# If a Kohan married a giyeurit by orthodox rabbi, is it a legitimate marriage?

Tags: halacha, marriage, conversion-to-judaism, kohen-priest, mistakes

If a Kohan was married to a giyuerit by an observant ("orthodox") rabbi, and if the rabbi wasn't aware that he was marrying a Kohan and not an Israelite, is the marriage legitimate?

Sources requested as well.

Comment: Unlike in other religions, the rabbi at a wedding doesn't effect the marriage. He's just there to make sure everyone is doing their parts right. In theory (and this is a Bad Idea™ lest people make mistakes) one need not have a rabbi at a wedding.

Answer (score 6):

The marriage is valid regardless of the knowledge of the rabbi had at the time. 
The prohibition for a kohen to marry a giyores is only a Lav- negative commandment and thus would not invalidate the marriage the same way a brother and a sister marrying would, for that is a forbidden relationship and the children would be mamzerim.  Rather the children of this relationship would be considered Chalalim- disqualified kohanim and they may not marry kohanim and they and their father may not Duchan.  (Shulchan Aruch Even Haezer 6:8)

It is of course still prohibited to be married in the first place and after the fact to remain together, and every time they are intimate they are transgressing a serious prohibition.

For more on this prohibition, see [this Aish.com article](http://www.aish.com/atr/Kohen_Marriages.html):

> There is another issue, however. It is important to check if the
>   "Kohen" is a real "Kohen." How reliable is the Kohanic tradition in
>   the family? Just because someone's last name is "Cohen" does not mean
>   that he necessarily has the status of a Kohen. To be considered a
>   Kohen, one must have an unbroken tradition, as well as other factors
>   too numerous to mention here. (Nevertheless, most people who have the
>   name Cohen also have the status as Kohen.)

Rav Joseph B. Soloveitchik in a powerful address to the RCA rabbinical convetion in 1973 told the story of a couple ([link](https://www.ou.org/jewish_action/04/2013/the_rav_speak/)):

> The Rav told the story of a young man and woman who sought his
>   assistance. She was a convert who later fell in love with this young
>   man, whose increased interest in Judaism she sparked. The two became
>   engaged and he visited his grandfather’s grave, where he discovered
>   that he is a kohen. What could the Rav do? A kohen may not marry a
>   convert and therefore, tragically, this couple could not wed. However,
>   we must unhesitatingly surrender to the will of the Almighty. With
>   sadness in his heart, the Rav shared in the suffering of this woman
>   who had to lose the beloved man she helped bring back into the fold.
>   She valiantly walked away from him, surrendering to the Almighty’s
>   will.

Comment: Okay, so even though the marriage is legitimate, the Kohan is under constant obligation to divorce the giyuerit to get back his priestly status, or is it not that simple?

Comment: Not so simple.  Cylor, but I guess in this case you can't :-)

Comment: Ah, of course, it's never simple. :) You can't divorce as a Kohan? The "you can't" seemed like it was missing more to the sentence.

Comment: @JBear The kohen **must** divorce the woman with a legitimate get. Even so, the children maintain their status as chalalim (disqualified) and the daughters  and granddaughters (even from a son) are also forbidden to marry kohanim The father can be "requalified" after the divorce.

Comment: I [edited out](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/75/how-should-i-cite-an-answer-elsewhere/76#76) a copy/paste of an entire article from Aish. Please consider summarizing pertinent points, using selective quotations as necessary. I think you answered the question in your first paragraph, so the Aish article and the Rav story seem like bonus material, anyway.

Comment: @IsaacMoses thank you. It's hard to pull out the main points because since I didn't write myself I feel weird breakaking it apart.  I feel I don't have "ownership" over it to be שולח יד. I just wanted to add in that rybs story for effect, it's just so powerful.

Comment: @Mefaresh if there are points in it that are pertinent here, you can rewrite them in your own words and acknowledge that you got help from that article.

Comment: How do we even know he was a kohen? Plenty of people added the surname "Kohen" when they came to America and may not even be kohanim. I could see leniency because he is a safek.

Comment: See link to Aish.com cited in answer.  Mentions this possibility. But today we work with the assumption that they are. Furthermore that is only one safely. This is a lav. Still would be assur unless you can conjure up a legit second safek.

Comment: Nowadays the mitochondrial DNA can be tested. I believe that there are features that have been ascribed to Cohanim. Since this DNA is passed down patrilinearly, it can serve as supporting evidence (not 100% conclusive though)

Comment: @Epicentre chazaka on halacha is stronger than DNA IMO

Comment: That is why I said _supporting_ evidence. In any case there are also surnames Azulay and Katz at least, and the variations of Cohen - Kahn, Kahane, Kagan, Kogan.

Answer (score 1):

It is a "valid" marriage in that it needs a Get to dissolve it and if she had children during this period through another man, they would be mamzeirim (and she and the man would be guilty of adultery).